# Local Apache Server on LAN cannot connect to the internet

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have Wordpress running on WAMP on a machine on my LAN. and its all working fine and the website is accessible from computers within the LAN.
the problem is that I need to install some wordpress plugins that need internet access. and Wordpress on the local server isn't able to connect to the internet.
As I said I am on a LAN. The server is running windows 7 and the internet connection is via a windows server 2008 running TMG.

Comment: You will have to provide much more details. There is no way _we_ can _guess_ the topology of _your_ network setup. Most likely this is not an apache or wordpress issue, so please change the tags on this question. Login onto the system and test internet connection directly. This has to work, before that there is little sense to think about your http server to use it. Start by checking the routing table, probably no or a wrong gateway is configured.

Comment: Internet connection is fine, i can connect to the internet on the server machine, IE, Firefox all work fine.

Comment: That does _not_ mean, the system can directly connect to the internet.  Those might also use a proxy. So _did_ you check _how_ the connection to the internet is configured or did you just fire a browser and load some page?

Comment: Oh, and I just see you write about using a MS TMG system inbetween your server and the internet. Did you edit your question? Didn't see that before, sorry. In that case a direct connection cannot work I guess, but I have very little experience with MS products. Sine you use their products you have payed for them. By that you payed for technical support from their side. I suggest you call MS and ask them. Why as here if you have payed support?

Comment: I did not edit my question, and yes of course its paid, we are a corporation, but how are MS involved in this? the MS systems in place are run by me as I am the sys admin and as far as i can tell i don't have any problems with MS products. naturally i use a proxy configuration on IE and Firefox to connect to the Internet since I am behind a firewall. is there some kind of setup/config that can be done on Apache/Wordpress to enable the them to connect to the internet?

Comment: MS is involved insofar as it is the producer of that MTG system. If you payed for it then you payed for support from their side, as far as I know. I only suggest to use the support you already payed for. About connecting to the internet: browsers to not necessarily need a proxy to connect to the internet through a firewall. but it looks like in this case. So you need to find out _how_ a client can use that TMG system. A proxy strategy is only one possibility, as said I do not know that system. What does its documentation say?

Comment: The question if a wordpress module can use the same strategy cannot be answered without knowing that strategy I am afraid. You must find out more details, sorry.